# Error when converting TPanel To TJvPanel

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, gexperts

In a VCL project on the Delphi 10.1.2 IDE, when I try to convert a `TPanel` (placed on a TToolbar) to a `TJvPanel` with the "Replace Components" GExpert 1.3.8.47:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

which is very strange since neither `TPanel` nor `TJvPanel` have a "ImageList".

So how can I convert a `TPanel` to a `TJvPanel` with the "Replace Components" GExpert?

Comment: Contact support for "GEpert", whatever that is.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the typos: Should have been "GExpert" and not "GEpert". "GExpert" is a very famous Delphi IDE add-in which almost everybody knows.

Comment: The Panel is placed on a Toolbar, and Toolbars do have an ImageList property. I guess that is somehow related.

Comment: I also wonder why the add-in would try to save something to a file since the task is only to replace a control which doesn't need to save anything.

Comment: Contact the vendor for the component

Comment: @David - both GExperts and TJvPanel (from the JVCL) are open source